# Linear System: Determine whether it is consistent

Tags: linear-algebra

Problem:

$$
\begin{align}
5y+w=1 \\
2x+5y-4z+w=1
\end{align}
$$

What I've done:
-1 times first equation in order to get rid of $5y$ and $w$.
Then, when I add first and second equation, the equation becomes $2x-4z=0$
And I'm stuck right here.

Thanks.

Comment: we have $5y+w=1$ taking this into account can we choose numbers for which $2x+5y+w-4z=1$ or as $5y+w=1$ we have $2x-4z+1=1$ or $2x-4z=0$ we have infinite many options to choose $x$ and therefore $y$ or vice versa this freedom of choice can be formalized in the rank property of a matrix http://www.math.tamu.edu/~fnarc/psfiles/rank2005.pdf

Answer (score 1):

To show whether it is consistent, you just have to exhibit a solution.

Let $w=1$ and let the other variables be $0$.

Comment: Why do you set w to 1?

Comment: I just need a solution. I can also set $y = \frac15$ and set the other variables to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

The system is consistent because the matrix of the system and the augmented matrix:
$$\begin{bmatrix}0&5&0&1\\2&5&-4&1\end{bmatrix}\enspace\text{ and }\enspace\begin{bmatrix}0&5&0&1&1\\2&5&-4&1&1\end{bmatrix}\enspace \text{ resp. }$$
have the same rank, which is the maximal rank, $2$.

Furthermore, the set of solutions is an affine subspace of $K^4$ ($K$ denotes the base field) of codimension $2$, i.e. of dimension $4-2=2$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you system is consistent and you have infinitely many solutions.

You may pick $x$ and $z$ such that $x=2z$ and solve for $y$ and $w$ such that $5y+w=1.$

For example $$(x,y,z,w)=(2,1,1,-4)$$ is such a solution.